# Bot won't messsage on join (djs)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

My bot doesn't send the message on join.

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const linkId = pool.createLink(client.id);
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('reCAPTCHA Verification')
        .setDescription(`To gain access to this server you must solve a captcha. The link will expire in 15 minutes.\nhttp://${domain == '' ? 'localhost:8050' : domain}/verify/${linkId}`)
        .setColor('BLUE')
    member.send(embed)
})
```

Comment: what does it do instead? are there any errors?

Comment: nothing no error or anything else

Comment: Hi @Tired. When asking a question, you should share as much as you can on the problem. What does your environment look like? Meaning, what browser, what versions of the libraries in question you're using, what have you tried so far that worked, and the specific situations in which it does not work. This alone is not enough for anyone to chip in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you aren't getting any errors in your code, I'm assuming the `guildMemberAdd` event isn't triggering for you at all. This could be quickly confirmed by putting a `console.log` statement inside of your `guildMemberAdd` event handler in your current code, and having a member join the guild.

The only reason I can think of that this would occur, is the Discord API's relatively new `intents` feature. You need to subscribe to specific intents in order to reliably receive the affiliated events. `guildMemberAdd` is on [the list of events](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#gateway-intents) that may require subscription to an intent.

Here's one possible fix you'll need to implement wherever you are defining `client`:

```
const intents = ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MEMBERS"];
const client = new Discord.Client({intents: intents, ws:{intents: intents}});
```

If you are already properly using intents, then I would recommend using `console.log` as aforementioned to ensure the `guildMemberAdd` event is triggering. If not, then this is the answer. Note that you must use discord.js v12.x.x to use intents, so if you're using an older version you'll need to update to fix your issue.

You *may* also need to enable the below setting for your bot on its discord developers page, as I think `guildMemberAdd` is part of a privileged intent:

[image]

Relevant resources:
[List of intents and associated events](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#gateway-intents)
[General info about intents](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html)

Comment: On top of this, you also have to make sure the user you are sending the message to doesn't have the bot blocked, and doesn't have their settings configured such that they do not receive the DM. You can't "detect" this before sending the message, but you can add a `.catch()` to the end of your `member.send()` to execute some other code when the bot is unable to send the message to the member that joined.