# Discord.js weclome command

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm very confused why this isn't working. There are no errors in the console.
Its not sending messages when a user joins or leaves

````
    member.roles.add(member.guild.roles.cache.find(i => i.name === 'Member'))

    const welcomeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

    welcomeEmbed.setColor('#5cf000')
    welcomeEmbed.setTitle('**' + member.user.username + '** is now Among Us other **' + member.guild.memberCount + '** people')
    welcomeEmbed.setImage('https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/93GAa4wm3z4HbenzLbxWeQ-650-80.jpg.webp')

    member.guild.channels.cache.find(i => i.name === '〔〕arrivals').send(welcomeEmbed)
})

client.on('guildMemberRemove', member => {
    const goodbyeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

    goodbyeEmbed.setColor('#f00000')
    goodbyeEmbed.setTitle('**' + member.user.username + '** was not the impostor there are **' + member.guild.memberCount + '** left Among Us')
    goodbyeEmbed.setImage('https://gamewith-en.akamaized.net/article/thumbnail/rectangle/22183.png')

    member.guild.channels.cache.find(i => i.name === '〔〕departures').send(goodbyeEmbed)
})
//Welcome & goodbye messages end\\
    
});


client.login(config.token);```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bot won't messsage on join (djs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65282277/bot-wont-messsage-on-join-djs)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the Discord API's relatively new `intents` feature. You need to subscribe to specific intents in order to reliably receive the affiliated events. `guildMemberAdd` and `guildMemberRemove` are on [the list of events](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#gateway-intents) that may require subscription to an intent.

Here's one possible fix you'll need to implement wherever you are defining client:

```
const intents = ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MEMBERS"];
const client = new Discord.Client({intents: intents, ws:{intents: intents}});
```

You may also need to enable the below setting for your bot on its discord developers page, as I think `guildMemberAdd` and `guildMemberRemove` are parts of a privileged intent:

[image]

Relevant resources:
[General info about intents](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html)
[List of events requiring intents](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#gateway-intents)
[A similar question that I previously answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65282277/bot-wont-messsage-on-join-djs/65282536#65282536)

Comment: I've already enabled server member intent, so that's not the problem. I'll try the other thing you suggested

Comment: One thing you can do is add a `console.log` to the top of your `guildMemberAdd` and `guildMemberRemove` handlers, so you can tell us if the event is getting triggered at all. If it is, meaning the console logs executed, then the issue is not intents.